# RelativeLayout inside ScrollView with allignParentBottom

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

i have a fragment with a RelativLayout that holds a TextView at the top, a LinearLayout (which is filled dynammically with CheckBoxes) in the middle and a Button at the bottom.

The problem is that i need scrolling if too many CheckBoxes are added. The Button is alligned using the attribut layout_alignParentBottom and is displayed at the top of the screen. This attribut is not working with Scrollview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/show_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hold_check_boxes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/show_content" />

<Button android:id="@+id/save"            
    android:layout_width="150dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

any suggestions?

EDIT: with ScrollView

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"         
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >            

    <RelativeLayout              
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"             
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">                               

          <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/show_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_border" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hold_check_boxes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/show_content" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/save"            
            android:layout_width="150dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />     

     </RelativeLayout>    
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Where did you add scrollview? Your LinearLayout must be wrapped in the scrollview.

Comment: i've tried 

<ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout>
....
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


and 

<LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout>
....
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

both of them displayed the button with the allignparentbuttom attribut at the top of the screen

Comment: Please post the updated code with the scrollview.

Comment: edited the original post

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this without taking  as parent. The only thing you have to do is take Linearlayout in ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/show_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/save"
        android:layout_below="@+id/show_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hold_check_boxes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hold_check_boxes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/show_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hold_check_boxes"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/save" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: yes, i already figured that out. checkboxes are scrollable then and the button is always at the bottom. what i want is the button below the checkboxes. so, the button is visible at the bottom after scrolling to the bottom of the checkboxes. i hope it is understandable what i try to do

Comment: this works if scrolling is needed but the problem is that the checkboxes are created dynamically and most of the time scrolling isnt necessary. in that case the button should be at the bottom of the screen instead of directly below the checkboxes

Comment: for that create your own logic play with Visibility property of controls.